# How To Add buttons to the toolbar which appears in TinyMce when you click over images

Tags: customization, images, tinymce

Using Wordpress 4.4 I need to add a custom button to manipulate images. The button should appear when the user clicks on an image, next to other buttons.

An example of the other buttons:

[image]